# How not to pass a value by reference to a same object property?

Tags: javascript

```
function A(){}
var B = {};

var a1 = new A();
var a2 = new A();
var b1 = B;
var b2 = b1;

A.prototype.prop = "A's Property";
b1.prop = "B's Property";
a1.prop = "Not Prop";
alert (a1.prop + " not equal to " + a2.prop);
b2.prop = "Not Prop";
alert (b1.prop +" still equal to "+ b2.prop);
```

As you can see, b2.prop can't pass by value, how to pass by value without changing the property name?

Comment: Can you clarify your conception of "passing by value"? Because usually, "passing" implies, well, passing arguments to functions. You're not defining any function, so that's probably not what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a clone method:

```
function clone(o) {
    if(!o || 'object' !== typeof o)  {
        return o;
    }
    varc = 'function' === typeof o.pop ? [] : {};
    var p, v;
    for (p in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            v = o[p];
            if (v && 'object' === typeof v) {
                c[p] = clone(v);
            } else {
                c[p] = v;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

and then use it to clone your `b1` object:

```
var b1 = B;
var b2 = clone(b1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how to give `b1` and `b2` different values for `prop`? Because the way you are doing it, you can't. `b1` and `b2` reference the same object. You would have to create a new object for each of them.

```
var b1 = {};
var b2 = {};
// b1 and b2 can have independent prop values now
```

Comment: No, a single instance of an object can not have two values at a time for a single property.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `b2` to `b1` which is just a reference to `B`.

You must assign `b2` to a clone of `b1` if you want them to have different property bags.